# Image matching using OpenCV ORB

Tags: android, opencv, image-recognition

I'm writing an app in which the user takes a photograph of a 'code', and then I'm trying to identify which 'code' they photographed using feature detection in OpenCV.

The user can take a photograph, then I iterate through all the stored 'codes' on the device, matching each and selecting the code with the highest number of good matches.

The code for feature detection looks like this:

```
public Integer detect(Mat img1, Mat img2) {
    Size sz = new Size(200, 200);

    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor
            .create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);

    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher
            .create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

    Mat resizeimage = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize(img1, resizeimage, sz);
    img1 = resizeimage;

    Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
    descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

    Mat resizeimage2 = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize(img2, resizeimage2, sz);
    img2 = resizeimage2;

    Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
    descriptor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
    int DIST_LIMIT = 80;
    List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
    List<DMatch> matches_final = new ArrayList<DMatch>();

    for (int i = 0; i < matchesList.size(); i++)
        if (matchesList.get(i).distance <= DIST_LIMIT) {
            matches_final.add(matches.toList().get(i));
        }// end if

    MatOfDMatch matches_final_mat = new MatOfDMatch();
    matches_final_mat.fromList(matches_final);

    mTotalMatches = matches_final.size();

    Scalar RED = new Scalar(255, 0, 0);
    Scalar GREEN = new Scalar(0, 255, 0);

    Mat outputImg = new Mat();
    MatOfByte drawnMatches = new MatOfByte();

    Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2,
            matches_final_mat, outputImg, GREEN, RED, drawnMatches,
            Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    Bitmap imageMatched = Bitmap.createBitmap(outputImg.cols(),
            outputImg.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Utils.matToBitmap(outputImg, imageMatched);

    return mTotalMatches;
}// end detect
```

The images that I'm identifying look like this, with the hexagon overlay in different locations:

[image: hexagonal coe]

The problem I'm having is that the wrong image is detected, usually only by a good matches count of around 5-10. I've tried playing around with the distance limit for good matches but I can't seem to get it to work. Is it possible that this is caused by the image quality of the photo taken? Or is it an error in my code?

Comment: Sorry to say this, but feature descriptors like ORB aren't well-suited to low-texture, repetitive images like the one you posted. You might want to pursue a different approach.